# Font outlines for svg file with the smallest size?

Tags: fonts, svg, sketch-app, web-fonts, file-size

I noticed that when turning a image with many texts into svg file, it'd be larger than its png file. The strokes of the outlines, which are part of font before we turning it into outlines, takes the most of the file size.

[image: svg file size compared with png file size]

I wonder if there's a font with the smallest size or minimal strokes, after we turn it from font into outlines. Maybe it's a geometrically crafted font or very similar to Futura without any correction from perfect shapes.

P.S., Maybe I can use the most common font like `courier` and not turn it into outlines to make it small, but I still wonder if the question above can be solved or not.

P.S.2, Or is there any better way to do with svg file?

Comment: This is a great question, but I'm curious why you can't just leave the text as SVG text instead of converting it to paths. Using svg text is going to significantly reduce your file size

Comment: @Scribblemacher SVG text needs users to install the font file in their computer. Some font file is rarely used in daily life, but may be useful in graphic design. So I have to convert text to path.

Answer (score -1):

**First question:**
Why are you exporting text out as an image? There isn't a wrong answer; I'm curious as to what you're doing :)

I don't know what font is "the smallest," but you can optimize what you have though!

[ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com) is a great tool to shave bytes off of the file size, and [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com) is even more magical for PNGs with an alpha channel. I even [wrote out a way to create a system wide shortcut](http://www.alloftheabove.audio/episodes/33) to send selected image files to ImageOptim because I do it so much. Scroll to the bottom of that page for screenshots.

For JPEGs, I use [JPEG Mini](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jpegmini/id498944723?mt=12&at=10lwgb).

If you're comfortable with the command line, [ImageOptim CLI](https://github.com/JamieMason/ImageOptim-CLI) is a free tool that allows you to run a batch of images through all three of these image optimizers. And here's one for SVG's — [SVGO](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/10/22/optimizing-svg-web/).

Hopefully this can help you in your quest to squeeze out all the bytes you can!

Comment: Because I needed to show a mind map on my website, and I thought svg file would be better for viewing text and have smaller file size. :)

Comment: @chenghuayang •  

Depending on your needs, it might be a better user experience to embed a mind map. http://www.mindmeister.com/blog/2010/10/11/embedding-mind-maps/